# Javafx webview don't work properly with arabic characters

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

When I switch from Azul Zulu jdk (that has Javafx) to Amazon Corretto Jdk, the WebView instead of showing the string "عربي" it shows a series of vertical rectangles ▯▯▯▯▯▯.
My line of code is :

```
webView.getEngine().loadContent("عربي");
```

I tried to add : `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` to my string without success.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) constants, for example `\u0627` for letter ALEF.

Comment: If Zulu works, why change?

Comment: FWIW, I tried to display your string in a WebView on a Mac and it displayed fine.  I was using JavaFX 17.0.1 and OpenJDK build 17.0.1+12-39.  On this system, the output of: `System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset())` was `UTF-8`.  Check what it is for your system.  Further info on default charsets is in the [JEP400 description](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).